# A common init function for all IntegerLiteralConvertible in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I've currently made a protocol that has a bunch of redundant initializers

```
public protocol ConvertibleUnit {

    ///The raw value in `self` unit type
    var value : Double { get set }

    ///The value in base units (i.e. for distance this would be `Meters`
    var valueInBaseUnits : Double { get set }

    ///Do not interact with this directly
    var data : UnitValueData { get set}

    init(_ v : Double)
    init(_ v : Float)
    init(_ v : Int)

    var unitType : ConversionEnum {get}
}
```

Basically I was hoping to make a protocol extension and define a default version of `Float` and `Int`

I tried some options (both of which error) similar to:

```
extension ConvertibleUnit {
    init(_ v : Float) {
        init(Double(v) )
    }

    init(_ v : Int) {
        Self(Double(v))
    }   
}
```

This lead me to wonder if there was a common protocol such as `IntegerLiteralConvertible` that I could call the initializer with, but that also doesn't seem to work.

Basically is there a way to make (i guess a generic?) initializer that accepts anything that can be converted to a double and then will do a generic init.

```
init<T : ANYTHING_THAT_CAN_BE_CONVERTED_TO_DOUBLE>(_ v : T) {
   let d : Double = Double(T)

   // Do stuff to init
}
```

#### Update

- tried using Self.init(Double(v))

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `self.init(...)` (note the lowercase) when calling the initialiser:

```
extension ConvertibleUnit {
    init(_ v: Int) {
        self.init(Double(v))
    }

    init(_ v: Float) {
        self.init(Double(v))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the protocol extension try using `Self.init(Double(v))`. This will allow you to use a single initializer but get multiple from all conforming types. For more about using protocols and extensions read my blog post: http://manavgabhawala.me/#/blog/protocol-oriented-programming

Also, if you want to use generics there are two protocols you can use: `FloatLiteralConvertible` and `FloatingPointType`. You can find all protocols in the standard library here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/#protocols

You can also use `IntegerType` and `IntegerLiteralConvertible` (which you mentioned).